# When new a Form, will I get a process or thread?

Tags: c#

In C#, I have two Forms: mainForm and form1.

```
class Form1; //...
class mainForm {
    //...
    void f() {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to wait for the form1 to exit and continue the following work in the mainForm. But I don't know the form1 is implemented as a process or a thread and how to get its ID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is neither. It runs on the same UI thread as your other form(s) unless you go out of your way to do something clever, with the message pump handling messages to all of them.

What is it that you want to do? Normally keeping the *reference* to the second form instance is sufficient for sending messages, etc.

To wait for the second form to finish, use `ShowDialog()`, or if you are in a form, `ShowDialog(this)`.

Comment: Thank you Gravell and Said very much. I get it.

Comment: And I have another question. I think I can do it by using PeekMessage. But I don't know how to do it in .Net. I know how to wrap a Win32 API in .Net, but I think that is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

form1 runs on the same Main Thread and you can simply run form1 as modal dialog like

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.ShowDialog(this); //mainForm waits till form1 finishs its work
//extra work in mainForm
```